# Como invocar a própria função

Tags: python

```
def R(n):

    if n == 1:
        return  1
    else:

        return  1/1/x-1/R(1/x+2/x)*n/1*n   
x=int(input("entre com x:"))

print(R(2))
```

ela faz o seguinte pega 1 divide 1/x -1  a cada
iteração ela  divide 1/ 1/x -1/3/x 
ela soma 2/x acada iteração minha duvida e como chamar função
o erro dela 
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison

Comment: tinha que montar recursivo e transformar iterativo porem fiz code mas não sei  aonde posso chamar função? ai bug tudo

Comment: O que a função `R` deveria  fazer ?

Comment: 1/1/x-1/3/x-1 se reparar cresce 2/x cada iteração ai deveria calcular isso

Comment: Sua dúvida é como definir a condição de parada da chamada recursiva ?

Comment: Ou como invocar a função durante a execução  da mesma?

Comment: exatamente isso invocar funçao

Comment: Poderia detalhar melhor na pergunta, usando o botão [edit], o que exatamente a sua função deveria fazer e o que está acontecendo atualmente?

Comment: Tem uma variável x não declarada dentro da sua função. Não entendi que você está calculando. A variável x lida fora da função não é passada para a função.

Answer (score 2):

É so usar o próprio nome da função - no caso, `R` - e chama-la da mesma forma como chama a mesma de fora.

para outros algoritmos que podem ser calculados com recursão, como fatorial, é mais fácil entender:

```
def factorial(n):
   if n == 1: 
       return 1
   return n * factorial(n - 1)
```

Com a notação usada, e como eu não conheço a função, eu não consigo entender o que você quer calcular com a sua função para conseguir reescreve-la de forma recursiva.

Do jeito que está escrita ali, vocẽ chama `R` recursivamente com o valor `(1/x+2/x)` mas `x` e uam variável global definida fora da função - portanto, exceto em um único caso  especial, `x`nunca vai ser igual a 1,  e sua função nunca vai atingir o valor de parada - a função só vai encerrar a recursividade, e começar a retornar os valores, quando for chamada com o valor "1".

E mesmo que você troque "x" por "n" na chamada a R na linha  `return  1/1/x-1/R(1/x+2/x)*n/1*n`, eu não acho que a expressão "1/x + 2 / x" vai convergir pra "1" - isso só acontece com o valor "3" em x - portanto acho que você precisa explica rmelhor a fórmula que deseja calcular recursivamente se quer mais ajuda que isso.

Comment: escrevi recursiva mas não roda

Comment: aumentei a resposta com amis algumas considerações.